# How can I combine 2 dataframe columns in Pandas/Python that have 'Hour' and 'Minutes' separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, time

I have a dataframe in Pandas/Python as below:

```
Hour   Minutes
14.0   37.0
5.0    42.0
```

How can I combine those two columns into one, and convert the time format so it looks something like this:

```
Time
14:37:00
5:42:00
```

Any advice or helps would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to coldspeed’s answer is using .apply function

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'hour':[14.0 ,5.0],'minutes':[37.0,42.0]})

df['time'] = df[['hour','minutes']].astype(int).apply(
    lambda x:pd.to_timedelta(f"{x['hour']}:{x['minutes']}:00"),axis=1)

print(df['time'])
```

Results are the same:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This worked like a charm for me! Really appreciate your suggestion on this!